# Display values and how many times they occured using a Dictionary

Tags: python

I've been told to

> By using a dictionary (or your solution to Part 4), write a method
>   at_least(a, n) that takes a list, a, and an integer, n, as arguments
>   and returns a list containing only the elements of a that occur at
>   least n times.  For complete marks, the list should contain the
>   elements in order of their first occurrence in a.

I was able to figure this without using a dictionary, with

```
def at_least2(a, n):
    return [x for x in a if a.count(x) is n]
```

I was wondering how I can write this using a dictionary?

The input is:

```
a = [-6, 8, 7, 3, 2, -9, 1, -3, 2, -4, 4, -8, 7, 8, 2, -2, -7, 0, 1, 
     -9, -3, -7, -3, -5, 6, -3, 6, -3, -10, -8]

def at_least(a, 2):
```

and the output:

```
[8, 7, 2, -9, 1, -3, 2, -8, 7, 8, 2, -7, 1, -9, -3, -7, -3, 6, -3, 6, -3, -8]
```

*Edit*:

I don't understand how a dictionary is being used, yet the output isn't in dictionary form? My understanding is that dictionaries have values for each object.  I'm not sure if I'm using the right terms.

Comment: Note: your `at_least2` function doesn't work.   (1) Your assignment requests "at least n", but your code tries to find *exactly* n. (2) `is` in Python tests identity, not equality.  You want `>= n` anyway, but even if you wanted "==", using `is` would only work when Python happened to reuse the same integer object.  (Imagine writing "117" on a card.  You might only have one card, in which case `117 is 117` is True, but you might have two such cards, in which case `(this) 117 is (that) 117` would be False, but you'd still have `(this) 117 == (that) 117`.)

Answer (score 1):

best option here is  `collections.Counter()`:

```
from collections import Counter
def atleast(a,n):
    c=Counter(a)
    return [x for x in c if c[x]>=2]

a = [-6, 8, 7, 3, 2, -9, 1, -3, 2, -4, 4, -8, 7, 8, 2, -2, -7, 0, 1, -9, -3, -7, -3, -5, 6, -3, 6, -3, -10, -8]
print atleast(a,2)
```

**output:**

```
[1, 2, 6, 7, 8, -9, -8, -7, -3]
```

Or you can also use `setdefault()`:

```
>>> a = [-6, 8, 7, 3, 2, -9, 1, -3, 2, -4, 4, -8, 7, 8, 2, -2, -7, 0, 1, -9, -3, -7, -3, -5, 6, -3, 6, -3, -10, -8]
>>> dic={}
>>> for x in a:
...   dic[x]=dic.setdefault(x,0)+1
... 
>>> dic
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2, -10: 1, -9: 2, -8: 2, -7: 2, -6: 1, -5: 1, -4: 1, -3: 5, -2: 1}
```

Comment: @RohitJain `Counter` returns an sub-class of `dict` only.

Answer (score 0):

Use defaultdict:

```
In [7]: l=[1,2,34,436,1,2,3,4,12,3,2,1]

In [8]: import collections
   ...: d = collections.defaultdict(int)
   ...: for x in l: d[x] += 1
   ...: 

In [9]: d
Out[9]: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 12: 1, 34: 1, 436: 1})
```

just a dict:

```
d = {}
[d.__setitem__(item,1+d.get(item,0)) for item in l]
print d

{1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 12: 1, 34: 1, 436: 1}
```

or using count:

```
d=dict( [ (i, l.count(i)) for i in set(l) ] )
```

get the items that occour more than once as a list:

```
In [17]: [x for x in set(l) if d[x] > 1]
Out[17]: [1, 2, 3]
```

get the items that occour more than once as a dict:

```
In [21]: dict( [ (i, l.count(i)) for i in set(l) if l.count(i) > 1 ] )
Out[21]: {1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use defaultdict. Haven't heard it mentioned in class

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code: -

```
>>> l=[1,2,34,436,1,2,3,4,12,3,2,1]
>>> dic = {}

>>> for x in l:
        if x in dic:
            dic[x] += 1
        else:
            dic[x] = 1


>>> dic
{1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 12: 1, 34: 1, 436: 1}

# Get list of (key, value) tuple, for key occuring more than once.
>>> list_new = [(key, value) for key, value in dic.iteritems() if dic[key] > 1] 
>>> list_new
[(1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 2)]

# Create dictionary out of list
>>> dic2 = dict(list_new)
>>> dic2
{1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2}
```

Comment: don't use `has_key()` it's deprecated. use `if x in dic`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I was trying this thing only. But I used `x in dic.keys()`. Didn't work so finally i used that..

Answer (score 0):

```
def atLeast(a,n):
    A = {}
    for i in a:
        if i not in A:
            A[i] = 0
        A[i] += 1 

    new_a = []
    for i in a: 
        if A[i] >= n:
            new_a.append(i)
    return new_a
```

for complete marks:

```
def atLeast(a,n):
    A = {}
    for i in a:
        if i not in A:
            A[i] = 0
        A[i] += 1 

    new_a = []
    Appended = {} 
    for i in a: 
        if i in Appended:
            continue 
        Appended[i] = 0 
        if A[i] >= n:
            new_a.append(i)
    return new_a
```

Answer (score 0):

My take on this, using only a `dict` and not `collections` etc...

For each element in `mylist`, create a value->list lookup, so we know that `value` is unique, and that `len(value)` is the number of occurences, and `value[0]` is the index of the first occurrence.

```
mylist = [-6, 8, 7, 3, 2, -9, 1, -3, 2, -4, 4, -8, 7, 8, 2, -2, -7, 0, 1, -9, -3, -7, -3, -5, 6, -3, 6, -3, -10, -8]
mydict = {}
for idx, val in enumerate(mylist):
    mydict.setdefault(val, []).append(idx)
```

Which makes `mydict`:

> {0: [17], 1: [6, 18], 2: [4, 8, 14], 3: [3], 4: [10], 6: [24, 26], 7: [2, 12], 8: [1, 13], -10: [28], -9: [5, 19], -8: [11, 29], -7: [16, 21], -6: [0], -5: [23], -4: [9], -3: [7, 20, 22, 25, 27], -2: [15]}

We can get the elements which appear more than once (this using a list comprehension):

```
something = [k for k, v in mydict.iteritems() if len(v) > 1]
print something
# [1, 2, 6, 7, 8, -9, -8, -7, -3]
```

But, to get that extra credit, we can then sort it to return the original order by using:

```
something.sort(key=mydict.get)
print something
# [8, 7, 2, -9, 1, -3, -8, -7, 6]
```